# Octopus downloading resulting configs

Tags: octopus-deploy

I like to see a way (ideally thru Octopus web interface) to download resulting .config files, after transformation.
Use case: look at environment A with package B and get B.config with all transformations applied so I can use B.config to debug locally using connection strings pointed to A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could enable the ["Custom Deployment Script"](https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/custom-scripts#Customscripts-Scriptsinpackagestepsscripts-configured-in-steps) and use the post deployment script section with [an artifact](https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/artifacts#Artifacts-Collectingartifactsusingscripts).